# docker-compose issue with starting order

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I started learning about docker-compose today and I am having the following issue.

```
version : '2'
services:
    myService1:
       build: .
       image: newimagename
       restart: always
       ports:
          - "13000:13000"
       links :
          - database1
       command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "172.17.0.1:3306", "--"]

    database1:
       image: mydatabaseimage
       ports:
        - "3306:3306"
       restart: always
       environment:
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
        - MYSQL_USER=somename
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=somepassword
```

Details:

The image mydatabaseimage is an image that is built from mariadb image, database entries populated.

myService1 is built from an existing dockerfile for a java project. The problem is that in order for dockerfile to compile the project, it requires database entries. To compile, it will try query some information from 172.17.0.1:3306.

When I run this docker-compose, it will run the dockerfile then it will fail at during java compilation, saying it cannot connect to right database. (I can run this docker-compose only if I already have a database image running in docker container prior...)

I have been looking at the tutorial in here https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ and tried to use wait-for-it.sh

I am wondering what would I have to do so that database1 image is run first, wait until completed, before myService1 even begins to run its dockerfile?

Thank you.

Comment: You need access to a running database in order to _build_?  If you actually can't fix that, then you need to put something like `wait-for-it` into the Dockerfile, but note that Docker will cache that build step (and the step after it that depends on live database data.)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `depends_on` within `myService1`.

```
version: "3"
services:
    myService1:
       build: .
       depends_on: database1
```